# make nvim-cmp not autoselect the 1st option

Tags: neovim

I'm using `nvim-cmp` as my completion engine, which is working fine, but would like to change the default behavior to disable the automatic selection of the first option. The reason is that, when the last word of a line has suggestions, pressing enter will apply the first suggestion instead of just inserting a newline.

For example, in haskell, typing

```hs
main = do<CR>
```

the `do` matches `diso~` from luasnip, and is replaced by something like

```hs
main = 2022-12-05T12:50:34
```

I would prefer the suggestions to be visible but none of them selected until tab is pressed, and if none is selected then `<CR>` is just a newline. Is this possible?

Comment: Run command `set completeopt?`, what is the output? Try to use `set completeopt=menu,menuone,noselect` to see if it works as expected.

Comment: @jdhao it's `completeopt=menu,preview,menuone,noselect` but changing it seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Answering my own question, I found out that when using `lsp-zero`, the configuration has to be done there. The documention in `advanced-usage.md` provides the exact solution, which I'm posting here:

```lua
local lsp = require('lsp-zero')
lsp.preset('system-lsp')  -- or recommended, or whatever...
lsp.setup_nvim_cmp({
    preselect = 'none',
    completion = {
        completeopt = 'menu,menuone,noinsert,noselect'
    },
})
lsp.setup()
```

Answer (score 3):

First set `completeopt=menu,preview,menuone,noselect` to configure auto-completion menu.

Then you have to modify your `cmp` plugin configuration for mapping of CR key :

```lua
local cmp = require'cmp'

cmp.setup({
  mapping = cmp.mapping.preset.insert({
    ['<CR>'] = cmp.mapping.confirm({ select = false }),
  })
})
```

See [cmp plugins documentation](https://github.com/hrsh7th/nvim-cmp/blob/main/doc/cmp.txt) for further explanations about `cmp.confirm` option.

Comment: Thanks, but this has no effect for my configuration. I figured out that `lsp-zero` was the culprit. There is a configuration example in file `advanced-usage.md` from `lsp-zero` that works exactly as intended.